# Quick.DB Add Tag Issue in Discord - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord.js, quick.db

I am making a Tags System on my Discord Bot with Discord.JS. Basically with Tags, you start by adding a tag with the name and content. Once added, running the tag command will return the content of the Tag. Theres other Tag Commands such as Tag Info (To get Tag Info), Tag list, edit tag etc.

I am experiencing issues with my Add Tag Command. Basically, what I am trying to do is add a line of code which is to check if the Tag Name already Exists. However, whenever I run the Add Command 2nd time or more with the same Tag Name, it will just override the name.

I've tried with this line of code:

```
  let tags = await db.fetch(`tags_${message.guild.id}-${name}.name`)
  if(!tags) return message.channel.send(`**Tags |** **Tag Exists!**`)
```

This should return a message response if the same Tag Name exists in the Guild But it is not working as expected.

For other Tag Commands I have, they kept getting `Cannot read property 'content' of null` error but I've somewhat resolved this with this snippet of code that uses the Try and Catch Statements.

```
} catch (e){
        if (e.message === "Cannot read property 'content' of null")
        return message.channel.send(`**Tag Not Found**`)
```

The Tags System uses Quick.DB for Database storing. It wasn't easy to get this all working right. I have an API Debug JSON Link that i've used to try and diagnose the problems. https://nate-devbot.glitch.me/api/coinslb

Please only look at JSON Formats like this:
[image]

The other data entries are old and were resolved earlier.

The full code to AddTag.JS: https://hastebin.com/neqasomisa.js

Comment: This will check if the tag doesn't exist ` if(!tags) ` to check if it exists you need to make `if(tags)` ! is a Logical not Reverse the result, returns false if the result is true

Comment: Seemed to fix the issue. Thank you